# How to update list of installed packages

Tags: installation, apt, kubuntu

I want to install a new distro KUBUNTU 13.10. Currently i'm running 12.04. I have separate partitions for `/usr` and `/boot` and `/` (root). I'll install with same config and will format only `/`.

I want to know that as all my installed applications will stay is `/usr` after installing new distro, is there any way to update list of installed packages, so that i won't be needing to re-install same packages?

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Your question is not very specific or clear to me.  Is there a reason you have separate partitions for essential directories?  You may find your answer in the man pages for apt-get:

```
man apt-get
```

Or search through all the man pages using the -k switch:

```
man -k installed packages
```